# Disable Keyboard Repeat from command line?

Tags: command-line, keyboard

Is it possible to disable the keyboard repeat functionality, as is needed by various Flash games,  through the command line?

Normally it can be disabled by going to settings -> keyboard and hitting the button, but I'm wondering if there's a command line / programmatic solution which I can implement into a program of mine.

Comment: Linux Mint is off-topic here, based on Ubuntu or not. Please ask on [unix.se].

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `xset` utility, which works on the X.org level, across desktop environments. (The `dconf` / `gsettings` solution is Gnome specific.)

To switch off keyboard repeat:

```
xset r off
```

To switch keyboard repeat on again, with the same delay and rate settings as before:

```
xset r on
```

See [man xset](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/xset.1.html) for details.

Answer (score 5):

Of course it should be possible :)

Open the Terminal and execute the following command to disable it:

```bsh
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/keyboard/repeat false
```

If you want to set it to default value, use `reset` option as following:

```
dconf reset /org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/keyboard/repeat
```

---

From [man dconf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dconf.1.html):

```
dconf write KEY VALUE
dconf reset [-f] PATH
```

- write: Write a new value to a key.
- reset: Reset a key or an entire directory. For directories, `-f` must be specified.

---

Also you can use `gsettings` instead of `dconf`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.keyboard repeat false
```

From [man gsettings](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gsettings.1.html):

```bsh
set    #  gsettings set SCHEMA [:PATH]  KEY VALUE
   Sets the value of KEY to VALUE. The value is specified as a serialised GVariant.

reset  # gsettings reset SCHEMA [:PATH]  KEY
   Resets KEY to its default value.
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable key repeat for the entire keyboard:

```
xset r off
```

To disable key repeat for a specific key (for instance the key `a`, keycode `36`):

```
xset -r 36
```

You can find the keycode of the key you want to disable by typing `xev` in a terminal and looking at the `keycode` value displayed.