# How to permanently disable key repeating?

Tags: keyboard

I did found this similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/576421/disable-keyboard-repeat-from-command-line/576424#576424) but the problem still pops up now and then later after executing such command.

The problem came back after I open random applications. Sometimes after opening google chrome, sometimes OpenGL-based application, sometimes a certain applications which eat much of the RAM & CPU.

Just for the record, the problem is while I'm holding down the key, it keeps repeating the key in which I don't want this behavior to happen.

For reference, my system is `5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` on xfce.

**Update**

- Initial work around is to set `Repeat Delay` to be highest and `Repeat speed` to be lowest. Anyway, it doesn't completely solve the problem but at least not let you face the full blown repeating key problem.

Comment: Thanks! It's right there in my question, but here again. Ubuntu `18.04` with xfce on top.

Comment: Ok, my apology. Yes that is from `uname`, anyway I remember it's Ubuntu `18.04`. If you need more info, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting the repeat delay and speed as you've already done for a workaround, try:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard repeat false
```

Source: [Ubuntu 18.04 Repeat Keys wont stay off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188068/ubuntu-18-04-repeat-keys-wont-stay-off/1188320#1188320)

Comment: Thanks. I tested, and it didn't work. Key repeating comes back right after I finished running an application